# How to copy an image from Power point to clipboard in C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I use the following code to save an image from PowerPoint to local disk:

```
var shape = presentation.Slides[1].Shapes[1];   
shape.Copy(); //copy a shape from a slide to clipboard          
bool imgOk = Clipboard.ContainsImage(); //check if copied shape is an image

if (imgOk)
{
       Console.WriteLine(imgOk.ToString());
       Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();                   
       string filepath = @"D:\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\img.jpg";                    
       img.Save(filepath);
}
```

There is only one slide in ppt with one picture. But picture does not get copied to clipboard. How to solve this?

Comment: What's `Console.WriteLine(imgOk.ToString());` for?

Comment: it's just to print true/false if image gets copied to clipboard, but it prints false

Comment: Well usually C# Arrays or Lists are zero based. btw. Did you use debugger and see for your self what is in Slides/Shapes and how many items are there ?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but Slides/Shapes arrays start from 1 rather than 0. If I put 0, then it crashes.

Comment: First of all you should be sure that the picture is the only shape on your slide. In Powerpoint 2010 and later there is under start/mark/selection (sorry, translating from german) a complete list of all shapes. I also would recommend that you name the picture-shape with a unique name and then you can access the shapes by this name; this omits the problem if it starts with 0 or not.
Did you make sure that nothing is copied to the clipboard? Try to paste the content e.g. in word. I would trust the first two lines of your code more than the rest.